# Lyapunov stability of all solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that all solutions to the homogeneous linear differential system $X'(t)=A(t)X$ is bounded on $t\in [0,\infty)$. Show that all solutions are Lyapunov stable.

Comment: Write down the general solution in terms of a basis of the space of solutions of the homogenous system. Then take two particular solutions $X_1,X_2$ with $||X_1(0)-X_2(0)|| \leq \delta$, and see what you can say about $||X_1(t) - X_2(t)||$.

Comment: @fgp I still do not know how to do. Here, we need to have $||X_1(t)-X_2(t)||<\epsilon$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Comment: You *need* to writen down $X_1,X_2$ more explicitly. How do particular solutions of a linear system look like (HINT: They're contain two parts...)